# Apache Ignite cache size limitation

Tags: caching, ignite

I am starting a project where I want to load a lot of data into Apache Ignite cache to perform certain computations. My original data load will be about 40Gb and that may grow 4 or 5-fold at certain times. I looked through the Ignite documentation and I didn't find anything in regards of size of the cache limitations. So, would it be fair to assume that as long as I have enough resources ( CPUs and RAM ) I can add as many Nodes as necessary without compromising the performance, which is speed of computations in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ignite scales horizontally. There's no explicit limit in the capacity of a table.

Comment: Thank you. I am not planning to use a table but a distributed hash map, but in this case it's probably the same. What about the volume of Data per Node. Are there any guidelines in terms of any limit I can allocate to a single Node?

Comment: Table == cache == distributed hash map. Your limit is going to be more a function of how many reads/writes per second than strictly how much can be stored. You'd need to benchmark probably.